# Maclaurin series of $\frac{1}{1+\sin x}$

Tags: taylor-expansion

Find the terms through degree four of the Maclaurin series of $f(x)$.

$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+\sin x}$$

My work:

The Maclaurin series for $\sin x$ up to degree $4$ is $x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$

The Maclaurin series for $\frac{1}{1+x}$ up to degree $4$ is $1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4$

I substituted $x - \frac{x^3}{6} + \frac{x^5}{120}$ for $x$ in $1 - x + x^2 - x^3 + x^4$

Did I do this right? 
Plugging this into WolframAlpha, I get this: http://goo.gl/SKddyh

Which doesn't seem like the answer in the text: $1-x+x^2-\frac{5x^3}{6}+\frac{2x^4}{3}$

Comment: @ABC Thank you for editing!

Comment: If someone needs a general series expansion at $x=0$ of the function $\frac{1}{1+\sin x}$, please see Theorem 1.2 at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123 or Section 1.6 at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this:

[Your equation, expanded](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Expand%281-%28x-x%5E3/6%2bx%5E5/120%29%2b%28x-x%5E3/6%2bx%5E5/120%29%5E2-%28x-x%5E3/6%2bx%5E5/120%29%5E3%2b%28x-x%5E3/6%2bx%5E5/120%29%5E4%29)

As you can see, what you plugged into WolframAlpha *was* the same equation as the answer in the text.

Answer (score 2):

You did it right. The answer on WolframAlpha is the same. Try typing "expand" in front on WA.

Answer (score 2):

Your answer is correct, but there is a somewhat simpler method. You are looking for a polynomial $P=a+bx+cx^2+dx^3+ex^4$ such that $P\times(1+x-\frac{x^3}6)\equiv 1\pmod{x^5}$. This gives (by comparing coefficients of $x^0,x^1,\ldots,x^4$) the equations
$$
  \begin{align}a&=1\\a+b&=0\\b+c&=0\\-\tfrac16a+c+d&=0\\-\tfrac16b+d+e&=0,
  \end{align}
$$
which you can solve straight away as $a=1$, $b=-1$, $c=1$, $d=-\tfrac56$, $e=\tfrac23$.

Comment: wish I could give this five +1s; just opened a new way of reasoning about series, for me. Thanks for posting!

Comment: Mod(x^5) why reason ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax Because the question ignores terms of degree $5$ or higher in $x$ ("1

Find the terms through degree four of the Maclaurin series...").

Comment: But then the x^6,x7.. term will also be there too isnt ? Whjch the mod will reduce to x^1,x^2.. ?

Comment: @Orion_Pax: The monomials $x^6,x^7,\ldots$ are multiples of $x^5$, so they vanish modulo $x^5$ as well as $x^5$ itself. In other words, the quotient ring $\Bbb Q[[X]]/(X^5)$ of the formal power series ring $\Bbb Q[[X]]$ is canonically isomorphic to the corresponding quotient $\Bbb Q[X]/(X^5)$ of the polynomial ring $\Bbb Q[X]$ (and both are of dimension $5$ as vector space over $\Bbb Q$).

Comment: Understood thanks

Answer (score 1):

You did it right and nothing has to be added to the answers you received.

I do not know if you were obliged to use these steps since there is a direct way of doing this expansion applying the basic rules, that is to say that the Taylor series of $f(x)$ built at $x=0$ just write (up to the fourth degree)
$$f(0)+x f'(0)+\frac{1}{2} x^2 f''(0)+\frac{1}{6} f^{(3)}(0) x^3+\frac{1}{24}
   f^{(4)}(0) x^4+O\left(x^5\right)$$ The value of the function and its first four derivatives are $1,-1 ,2,-5,16$ (they are easy to evaluate bcause $sin(0)=0$ and $cos(0)=1$).

For sure, you arrive to your result.

You also have another way : replace in the denominator $sin(x)$ by its Taylor expansion and perform the long division of numerator by denominator.

You have done a good job ! Congratulations.

Answer (score 0):

For $k,n\in\mathbb{N}=\{1,2,\dotsc\}$, partial Bell polynomials $\textrm{B}_{n,k}$ satisfy
\begin{equation}\label{bell-sin=ans=0}\tag{BWSC}
\textrm{B}_{n,k}\biggl(1,0,-1,0,\dotsc, \cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}{2}\biggr)
=2^{n-k}\cos\frac{(n-k)\pi}2 R\biggl(n,k,-\frac{k}{2}\biggr),
\end{equation}
where
\begin{equation}\label{S(n,k,x)-satisfy-eq}
R(n,k,r)=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{k-j}\binom{k}{j}(r+j)^n
\end{equation}
for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ and $n\ge k\ge0$ denotes weighted Stirling numbers of the second kind, see Carlitz's paper [1] below.

The formula \eqref{bell-sin=ans=0} and its proof can be found in Theorem 1.2 of [2] and Section 1.6 of [3] below.

By virtue of the Faa di Bruno formula and the equation \eqref{bell-sin=ans=0}, one can readily discover the series expansion
\begin{equation}\label{sin-recip-ser-expan}\tag{SQE}
\boxed{\frac{1}{1+\sin x}=1+\sum_{k=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{k}\Biggl[\sum_{\ell=0}^{\lfloor{(k-1)/2}\rfloor} (-1)^{\ell} (k-2\ell)! 2^{2\ell} R\biggl(k,k-2\ell,-\frac{k-2\ell}{2}\biggr)\Biggr]\frac{x^k}{k!}}
\end{equation}
for $|x|<\frac{\pi}{2}$, where $\bigl\lfloor{\frac{k-1}{2}}\bigr\rfloor$ stands for the floor function whose value is equal to the largest integer less than or equal to $\frac{k-1}{2}$.

References

1. L. Carlitz, *Weighted Stirling numbers of the first and second kind, I*, Fibonacci Quart. **18** (1980), no. 2, 147--162.
2. F. Qi, *Derivatives of tangent function and tangent numbers*, Appl. Math. Comput. **268** (2015), 844--858; available online at http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/j.amc.2015.06.123.
3. F. Qi, D.-W. Niu, D. Lim, and Y.-H. Yao, *Special values of the Bell polynomials of the second kind for some sequences and functions*, J. Math. Anal. Appl. **491** (2020), no. 2, Article 124382, 31 pages; available online at https://doi.org/10.1016/j.jmaa.2020.124382.